# Кластер Yandex Map API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, иконки, кластеризация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать определенную иконку кластера для определенных координат? Т.е., например, для координат 54.90 с.ш. и 27.55 в.д. — одна иконка (при этом в данной точке находится две метки), а для 53.90 с.ш. и 27.55 в.д. — другая иконка (при это в точке n меток)? Возможно ли такое вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы просто хотите их выделить цветом то существует вариант использования https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_pie_chart в этом случае вы располагаете метки в нужном месте с заданным цветом и кластер будет разного цвета в зависимости от координат.
Если вы хотите задать им кастомные иконки, то:
Зависит от того сколько таких иконок на карте и как часто они будут меняться. Если их две то легче всего создать два раличных кластеризатора https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create , задать им иконки и расположить в нужных местах.
Если же таких иконок много, то самым разумным путём будет создание remote object manager, реализация серверной части. В этом случае вы полностью управляете отображением на карте https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/ .